# how to format float number as integer?

Tags: python, formatting, string-formatting

I am looking for a common formatting formula, where I dont loose precision but on the other hand I have no decimal points if not necessary

```
4.00 => "4"
1.23 => "1.23"
```

I've tried this

```
print "%.2f" % numvar
```

But for 4.00 I get 4.00

This format should be param passed as parameter to other function (see **float_format** http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) so I don't need some if else solution.

Comment: Try using `'%g'`. It shows some numbers in scientific notation, but maybe it'll work for you.

Comment: Thank you, write it as an answer please. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `%g` formatting code.

```
>>> print '%g' % 3
3
>>> print '%g' % 3.1
3.1
>>> print '%g' % 3.14
3.14
>>> print '%g' % 3.14159
3.14159
>>> print '%g' % 3.1415926
3.14159
>>> print '%.6g' % 3.1415926
3.14159
>>> print '%.8g' % 3.1415926
3.1415926
>>> print '%.10g' % 3.1415926
3.1415926
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex:

```
import re

def form(f, prec, spec):
    return re.sub("\.0+$", "", "{:.{prec}{spec}}".format(f, prec=prec, spec=spec))
```

Output:

```
In [2]: form(1.23, 2, "f")
Out[2]: '1.23'  
In [3]: form(4.00, 2, "f")
Out[3]: '4'    
In [4]: form(1.2302, 4, "f")
Out[4]: '1.2302'    
In [5]: form(1.0000, 4, "f")
Out[5]: '1'
```

Or if you were ok with 1.10 becoming 1.1 you could just rstrip:

```
print("{:.2f}".format(f).rstrip(".0"))
```